# Pivot table design with multi-column PRIMARY key MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing

Can anyone instantly see a problem or bottleneck in the schema below? Reads are 90% of the operations, but I'd like to know if I'm shooting myself in the foot anywhere on the writes either.

**The Proposition**

Each object (row in another table) can be related to other objects. There can only ever be one record for each relation pair (pairs are directionally sensitive, so `X` to `Y` *can* co-exist with `Y` to `X`).

```
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| a_id  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| b_id  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                | 
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A typical request will be to get all *related* objects (for a given object `A`):

```
SELECT * FROM objects INNER JOIN relations ON id = b_id WHERE a_id = A
```

Relations are managed using a simple checkbox array in the UI. To save relations, I'd calculate the difference between checked/non-checked in the current set (objects will be paged in the UI), and then just insert/delete accordingly;

```
DELETE FROM relations WHERE a_id = A AND b_id IN(B,C)

# if these relations already exist, will fail silently
INSERT IGNORE INTO relations (a_id, b_id) VALUES (A,D), (A,E)
```

I *may* also need to query reverse-relations, using just `b_id` for selects - since it's not left of the index, will it be used at all? And if not, will adding a separate index on it induce significant overhead for writes?

Comment: What engine is the table? You might want to do the `DELETE / INSERT` within a single transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of adding a second index on `b_id` will outweigh any overhead for writes, since without the index, it will need to do a full table scan to filter by `b_id`.

As far as making the index on just `b_id` or `b_id, a_id` depends on the table engine, Since `InnoDB` stores the primary key in the secondary indexes, however `MyISAM` does not.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but with InnoDB, `b_id` is sufficient?

Comment: Say I had to use MyISAM (the system is distributed and InnoDB is not guaranteed) - would adding the `b_id, a_id` index impede on InnoDB? i.e. compromising for either/or?